# Making Web App fit to browser width using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Web App which looks good but it is not fitting to the browser width and shows scroll bar at bottom to scroll. I tried this code to make it work, it only puts the app at centre of screen but it doesn't fit to browser's width:

```
 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Application 2015').setStyleAttribute('left', '26%').setStyleAttribute('position','relative');
```

I also tried adding `.setWidth(100)` at last of above code, still it doesn't make Web App fit to browser's width.

My Web App needs to show application form in the centre and same white blank space on left and right side of the app.

Any idea on this one?

Thanks

Comment: A css style of "margin: 0 auto" should help you, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Albus Shin. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the app width same as the browser width, you should set the width to `"100%"` instead of `"100"`.

Also, if you want to center your content in the browser, set the width to a fixed width, like `"1000px"` or `"60%"`, and set the margin to `"0 auto"`, which means let the browser decide the left and right margin of the content. The content should be centered then.

Comment: Thanks for answer Albus Shin. I tried the second option you suggested, it worked with slight adjustment in pixel from 1000px to 800px. With 1000px there was more space on right in my app, so I had to try 800px. This is the code worked:  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Application 2015').setStyleAttribute('position','relative').setStyleAttribute('margin', '0 auto').setStyleAttribute('width', '800px');

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Application 2015');
app
  .setStyleAttribute('width', '90%') // 90% of browser window width
  .setStyleAttribute('margin','10px auto'); // 10px top and bottom margins, centered horizontally in browser window
```

Most standard CSS styles are supported by UI Service's `.setStyleAttribute()` method (on the UiInstance and its widgets). Setting `width` as % will resize your ui app with browser window resizing. But it will only go as narrow as your widest widget - after that you will see horizontal scrollbars appear.

However, styles-wise, UiApp will only get you so far. If you need a lot more control over the look of your app, build it using [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer azawaza, I really appreciate it. I tried like this it worked: var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Application 2015').setStyleAttribute('position','relative').setStyleAttribute('margin', '0 auto').setStyleAttribute('width', '800px');